# Pass multiple Func Expressions to C# method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics

The entity framework's DbEntityEntry has a method **Collection** which accepts lambda expressions to load entities.

```
DbCollectionEntry<TEntity, TElement> Collection<TElement>(Expression<Func<TEntity, ICollection<TElement>>> navigationProperty) where TElement : class;
```

In my project we are following repository pattern so to call this I have created a method in the repository which accepts the same as a parameter.

```
 TModel GetItem<TElement>(object[] id, Expression<Func<TModel, object>> navigationProperty = null,
        Expression<Func<TModel, ICollection<TElement>>> navigationCollection = null, string collectionEntity = "")
        where TElement : class;
```

From Business Logic layer I'm invoking the method as

```
 var model = _repository.GetItem(
                    new object[]
                    {
                        viewModel.Id
                    },
                    navigationCollection: x => x.ProductSubVersions,
                    collectionEntity: nameof(ProductStatusSubSystem.SubSystem));
```

Where x is the model defined for the BusinessManager and for Repository

```
public class ProductStatus : BaseModel
{
    public ProductStatus()
    {
        // ReSharper disable once DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructor
        ProductSubVersions = new List<ProductStatusSubSystem>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Name of the product
    /// </summary>
    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// product version validity start date
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// product version valid till
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime? ValidTill { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This field used to keep track of history of a product
    /// </summary>
    public int ProductNumber { get; set; }

    public bool DefaultProduct { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// all versions of this product
    /// </summary>
    public virtual List<ProductStatusSubSystem> ProductSubVersions { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// all fallback languages attached to this language
    /// </summary>
    public virtual List<ProductStatusLanguage> ProductStatusLanguages { get; set; }


}
```

Business Manager

```
public class BaseBusinessManager<ProductStatus, ProductStatusViewModel>, IProductStatusBusinessManager
{
}


 public class VersionBaseBusinessManager<TModel, TViewModel> : IVersionBaseBusinessManager<TModel, TViewModel>
    where TModel : class, new()
    where TViewModel : class, new()
{

    private readonly ICrudRepository<TModel> _repository;
}
```

But Now I have a strange requirement, where I need to load one more than one collection property from the entity (I want to load ProductStatusLanguages also). How can I define a list of  **Expression<Func<TEntity, ICollection<TElement>>>** with multiple types of TElement?

here is the repository method

```
public virtual TModel GetItem<TElement>(object[] id, Expression<Func<TModel, object>> navigationProperty = null, Expression<Func<TModel, ICollection<TElement>>> navigationCollection = null, string collectionEntity = "")
        where TElement : class
    {
        var entity = Table.Find(id);
        if (navigationProperty != null)
        {
            DatabaseContext.Entry(entity).Reference(navigationProperty).Load();
        }
        if (navigationCollection != null)
        {
            DatabaseContext.Entry(entity).Collection(navigationCollection).Load();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(collectionEntity))
            {
                DatabaseContext.Entry(entity)
               .Collection(navigationCollection)
               .Query()
               .Include(collectionEntity).Load();
            }
        }
```

**P.S:** after reading the comment of Ivan Stoev I wrote a Method which will accepts expression as a parameter and loads the collection

```
public virtual void LoadCollection<TElement>(TModel entity,
        Expression<Func<TModel, ICollection<TElement>>> navigationCollection, string collectionEntity = "") where TElement : class
    {
        if (entity == null)
            return;
        DatabaseContext.Entry(entity).Collection(navigationCollection).Load();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(collectionEntity))
        {
            DatabaseContext.Entry(entity)
           .Collection(navigationCollection)
           .Query()
           .Include(collectionEntity).Load();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not directly possible. May be you should resort to `string` overloads. To give you more concrete idea, please show the implementation of the repository method in question.

Comment: @IvanStoev I wrote a method which accepts Expression as a parameter is it a good Idea or better to a create an overloaded method which accepts string collection and to create a string collection have a method which accepts the expression and converts to string.